# Как реализовать быстрое подключение к БД для живого поиска?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Здравствуйте!

Я собираюсь сделать на сайте живой поиск (как в Google). Нашел достаточно много материалов на эту тему. Лишь из-за одного момента я не могу приступить. Мой уровень знаний достаточно мал и я не могу понять как мне решить следующую проблему:

Вот с сайта, при помощи Ajax поступает запрос на .php скрипт, который должен взять из базы инфу. Вопрос - как можно быстро подключиться к бд или вообще сделать это заранее? Объяснений я не нашел. Я так понял, что больше всего времени тратиться именно на подключение к бд. Подключаться к ней после ввода каждого символа не получится. Все будет виснуть. Во всех примерах, которые я видел просто писалось `$mysqli->query(...)`. Строк подключения там не было, словно оно уже как таковое имеется.

Я попытался вникнуть в систему "постоянных подключений", но так и не разобрался, что к чему. К тому же там ограничения на кол-во одновременных соединений есть.

Очень прошу помочь с этим вопросом. Из-за него буквально стоит весь проект.

Comment: Такие вещи стоит писать не на php.

Comment: А на чем тогда? Во всех примерах, которые я искал, использовался php. Но про подключение к бд там не было написано.

Comment: На чем угодно, кроме php. =) Python, Ruby, Node.js. Кто бы что ни говорил про то, как он типа хорошо развивается - но [php создан, чтобы умирать.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/179399/)

Comment: А вообще подобную вещь на php, наверно, можно реализовать, переделав скрипт в fastcgi-сервер (но лучше не надо)

Comment: Пробуйте пулл соединений http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: Да, я заходил на эту страницу раньше, но никак не могу найти, как установить постоянное подключение с помощью mysqli

Comment: А вот, нашел: "хоста нужно добавить префикс p:". Но где мне создавать такое подключение, если скрипт умирает после Ajax запроса? Откуда брать объект соединения с базой?

Comment: А вы не думали, что для "живого поиска" камнем преткновения станет запрос к БД вида `SELECT * FROM table WHERE somthing LIKE '%data%';`, а вовсе не отсутствие подключения к БД. Очень многое зависит от того, что за база и как она устроена. В jquery есть плагин autocomplete. Работает и не виснет.

Comment: Я думаю, что тут надо еще подумать про кеширование запросов. Должно сильно помочь. По БД надо построить индексы. И надо посмотреть про полнотекстовый поиск еще. Он работает шустрее `LIKE '%data%'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел ответ.

На странице, на которой будет производиться живой поиск, необходимо создать постоянное соединение с помощью mysqli:

```
/* Пермаментное подключение к БД */
$pMysqli = new mysqli('p:'.DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Для того, чтобы подключение было постоянным, необходимо добавить префикс "p:". Об этом я знал.

После этого, в начале php скрипта, к которому обращается ajax, необходимо написать ту же строчку. Если соединение уже существует, то никакого подключения не состоится, зато у вас уже будет объект соединения.

Пример:

*Страница, на которой есть форма живого поиска* - somepage.php

```
<?php
/* Пермаментное подключение к БД */
$pMysqli = new mysqli('p:'.DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
?>
<input type="text" id="liveSearchField">
<script>
    // Обработка клика по liveSearchField и создание ajax запроса
</script>
```

*Обработчик Ajax запроса* - handler.php

```
<?php
/* Получение уже созданного подключения или создание нового */
$pMysqli = new mysqli('p:'.DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$data = $pMysqli->query("SELECT Content FROM TestTable ORDER BY Content LIMIT 1");

/* Работа с полученными данными */
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

О том, как реализовать автодополнение наиболее оптимально.

Просто поиск в базе однозначно неэффективен: на один ввод пользователя может прийтись до десятка запросов, каждый из которых лезет в базу, в которой теоретически могут лежать хоть миллионы записей, а всякие wildcard поиски обожают [страдать](https://www.google.ru/search?q=sql%20wildcard%20performance), за ними надо внимательно следить, чтобы они действительно использовали индексы; кроме того, упоротый фронтенд, используя плечо в виде количества приходящих на сайт, может легко все положить, отправляя по запросу на каждую букву и мультиплицируя входящий трафик в два-три-пять раз. В общем, путь рабочий, и, более того, при должном усердии, работающий быстро, но не моментально и требующий поддержки; кроме того, каждый инсерт-апдейт будет кромсать индекс и быстродействие.

Как решить эту проблему? Во-первых, можно по старой привычке запихнуть все в оперативную память, во-вторых, можно использовать эффективные алгоритмы. Если в случае с базой и индексом скорость поиска будет составлять `n` или `log n` в лучшем случае (`n` - количество записей, по которым производится поиск), то префиксное дерево / префиксный бор и суффиксный автомат позволяют свести скорость поиска до максимальной длины строки - то есть, до константы. Про суффиксный автомат я не могу сказать, так как у меня все нет времени дочитать и собрать воедино прочитанное, а префиксный бор (далее - Trie), по факту, представляет собой почти что обычное дерево:

[image: Imgur]

Trie строится для некоторых последовательностей, по которым нужно выполнить поиск (в нашем случае это строки, или последовательности символов). Узел в Trie представляет собой структуру, в которой хранятся *значения*, о которых будет сказано чуть позже, и ссылки на дочерние узлы в виде map (ассоциативного массива) - каждый дочерний узел сохраняется с ключом типа сущности из последовательности (в нашем случае ключом будет символ). В виде значений хранятся либо непосредственно искомые значения, либо ссылки на них (например, айдишники, хотя если с ними придется еще раз лезть в базу, то этоабсолютно неэффективно).

При заполнении Trie последовательности преобразуются в ветви, идущие из начального узла, и в узел, соответствующий последней сущности из последовательности записывается значение, соответствующее этой последовательности. Если я реализую поиск по продуктам, и мне попадется запись "молоко", то я сооружу из нее ветвь из шести узлов (если они еще не существуют в этот момент), и в последний узел запишу сам продукт. Если после этого мне попадется "молоковод", то я сооружу ветвь из девяти узлов (первые шесть из которых уже существуют), и в "д" я запишу непосредственно молоковода.

[image: Imgur]

Зачем это все нужно? В случае, если а) загрузить это все в оперативную память, б) держать это там между запросами, чтобы не выгружать каждый раз (здесь с PHP будут проблемы, да, но демонов никто не отменял) и в) выгрузить вообще всю информацию, которая должна выдаваться при поиске (а это редко больше чем две-три строки), то поиск первых N результатов по такому дереву будет выполняться **за миллисекунду** даже на хреновом железе. Для поиска достаточно просто разложить строку на последовательность символов, найти соответствующий узел, и наполнять корзину поиска из текущего, а потом и дочерних узлов до тех пор, пока дочерние узлы не кончатся или корзина не заполнится доверху. В среднем *по больнице* сложность поиска будет составлять где-нибудь шестнадцать символов, что до невероятности безумно прекрасно по сравнению с полным проходом всего массива.

Единственная проблема Trie - это то, что по ней осуществляется префиксный поиск, и для поиска подстроки придется скармливать ей суффиксы один за одним (эффективный нечеткий поиск вообще сложно представить); также для эффективного поиска обычно рядом надо держать обычный мап вида `<id, Data>`, где и хранить сами данные, а в Trie лишь id искомых данных. По поводу расхода памяти - если представить, что на каждую структуру расходуется даже один килобайт памяти (что обычно оверкилл), то на каждую тысячу элементов будет расходоваться один мегабайт, что, в общем-то, копейки для современных машин. Ну и, конечно, нужно не забывать скидывать внутрь последовательности (строки) с предварительным преобразованием - Trie не найдет вам строку, если в ее начале оказался лишний пробел, а для регистронезависимого поика нужно скидывать все и искать в одном регистре. И, конечно, Trie надо регулярно обновлять по мере обновления сущностей в базе - лучше всего реализовать одновременно и функционал полной перезагрузки раз в N минут, и функционал обновления отдельной сущности при добавлении / удалении / апдейте.

Comment: Отличный ответ.